# Django: get_context_data for comments related post

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a `models`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    post_relation = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    comment_text = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

In my `views` I need get `comments` for `posts` in `get_context_data`:

```
class ResultsView(DetailView, FormMixin):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts.html'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comm'] = Comment.objects.filter(is_active=True)
        return context
```

But in `comm` i get all comments in db.

In `html`:

```
{% for comment in question.comments.all %}
<div class="media mb-4">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h5 class="mt-0">{{ comment.author }}</h5>
        {{ comment.comment_text }}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I try `{% for comment in comm %}`, try `{% for comment in comm.all %}` and always get all comments in db, not only comments in post.

Also I try fix this string in `views`: `context['comm'] = Comment.objects.filter(is_active=True)`, but don't have a result.

The answer seems to be very simple, but I've already spent several hours trying and reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
class ResultsView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'posts.html'
    form_class = CommentForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(
            **kwargs, comms=self.object.comments.filter(is_active=True)
        )
```

and then render with:

```
{% for comment in comms %}
    # …
{% endfor %}
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: The [**`related_name=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)
> is the name of the relation in *reverse*, so from the `User` model to the `Comment`
> model in this case. Therefore it (often) makes not much sense to name it the
> same as the forward relation. You thus might want to consider renaming the <s>`author`</s> relation to `comments`.